# Обратный геокодинг локации полученной ботом Telegram

Tags: python-3.x, telebot, geocoding

Не могу разобраться с `json` ответом, как, куда и где его использовать, чтобы работал.

- API ключ геокодинга есть, активен.
- по HTTPS работает

Бот получает локацию от пользователя и в ответе должен прислать адрес из координат.

```
import telebot, cfg, kb, lg,

from telebot import types
from requests import get


bot = telebot.TeleBot(cfg.token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, lg.hello1e, reply_markup=kb.ikb1)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["location"])
def location(message):
    if message.location is not None:
        bot.send_message == (message.location)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "latitude: %s; longitude: %s" % (message.location.latitude, message.location.longitude))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, lg.hello5u, reply_markup=kb.kbsu1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас же есть `message.location.latitude`, `message.location.longitude`. передавайте из в Яндекс, токен и примеры по https у вас имеются. и ответ от сервиса отдавайте пользователю в чат.

Comment: Все равно что-то не дошло, как управлять этими координатами), url="https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/", это получается, но как их вместе то совместить), извините, но что-то ну никак не дается))), можно примерчик)? Плиз)))

Comment: `https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=Your API key&geocode=37.611347,55.760241` из примеров https://yandex.com/dev/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/examples/geocoder_examples.html/

Comment: это то я понял))), блин как в код то встроить правильно)), вот в чем незадача), в handler этот. Как правильно то встроить этот get.request))). Сории за тупость)))).

Comment: `place = request...` (получение адреса из координат); `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '{}'.format(place))` ну или через `%s` как больше нравится

Comment: а request этот откуда брать то)?  из flask?, пишет- NameError: name 'request' is not defined. А как сделать через маркер %s ))? Благодарю!

Comment: `import requests`. так же как и у вас

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получил я апи ключ.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["location"])
def location(message):
    if message.location is not None:
        coord = str(message.location.longitude) + ',' + str(message.location.latitude)
        r = requests.get('https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=' + apikey + '&format=json&geocode=' + coord)
        
        if len(r.json()['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember']) > 0:
            address = r.json()['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember'][0]['GeoObject']['metaDataProperty'][
                'GeocoderMetaData']['text']
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ваш адрес\n{}'.format(address))
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не удалось получить Ваш адрес')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Крутяк конечно! Что сказать)! Огромный Респект и низкий поклон! Но выкидывать начал с ошибкой - (__init__.py:489 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: unsupported parse_mode" .   apikey это надо как то прописывать как то)? - вот тут например)? https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=

Comment: Определите выше строковую переменную `apikey`, например после токена бота. Конечно же она должна содержать ваш ключ разработчика Яндекс

Comment: Cлава Вам!!!! Огромный Респект)! Нижайший поклон! Супер мастер класс))) , так прям сходу и не получится без Мастера! Благодарю!!!

Comment: Лучшая награда это отмеченный решением ответ и голос за него. Спасибо за вопрос.

Comment: Низкий поклон от меня лично)! Благодарю!

Comment: А можно попросить показать Вас как добавить ошибку в код)?  Если (не может определить место точно, я добавил просто kind=house в https, нужен прям точный адрес))), а если не точный то без kind=house.   Или ошибку прям (что не может определить адрес по этой локации. Благодарю!

Comment: не совсем ясно что требуется. если задан параметр `kind` в запросе к апи геокодера яндекса, то в ответ будет получен ближайший дом. проверял на списке координат, которые возвращают мкр, районы и т.п., с параметром возвращается ближайший дом. + телеграм при отправке локации пишет с какой точностью.

Comment: Да, да, тут все верно, а ежели он не может определить дом, допустим село какое нибудь там, либо вообще пустое поле, выкидывает с ошибкой IndexError: list index out of range, вот как ее обойти))))?

Comment: отредактировал ответ. см `if`..

Comment: Мощно, конечно! Огромное Вам человеческое Спасибо! Очень выручили! Я так и думал что через  if.. не хватает просто знаний и опыта! Буду учится). Благодарю!

Comment: Доброго времени! Подскажите по данному примеру: А как сделать, чтобы в данном примере, (content_types=["location"]) мог присылать координаты и разшифровывать их не один раз, а допустим несколько, когда требуется не только получить саму локацию пользователя, но и следующим этапом, получить локацию, которую пользователь хочет (другую). как в такси(получил где ты, и получил куда хочу), причем отвечал разными кнопками? Благодарю! чтото никак не врублюсь, присылает одно и тоже)

Comment: в телеграм нет возможности ввести адрес для поиска, но вы можете перемещать маркер на карте и выбрать нужную локацию при отправке геопозиции

Comment: это да, я понял, тут все гуд!!!! Как мне сделать в одном этом хэндлере, возможность запуска карты, из разного меню: т.е. на данный момент (при нажатиий на кнопку отпрвить местоположение, бот высылает координаты и раскодирует, все ок), огромный респект за это!!!! Но как мне использовать тот же хэндлер второй раз, когда надо уже выбрать место определенное(посредством маркера - тут как раз так и надо и он присылает все оК тоже), но для другого меню, с другими кнопками? Благодарю! Я понимаю что как то надо с elif повозится, или надо хэндлер еще раз переписать)? Благодарю!

Comment: хендлер (обработчик) будет ловить все сообщения с указанным типом, в данном случае `location`, вне зависимости где и на какую кнопку нажал пользователь. если отправили локацию, хендлер её воспримит и обработает.

Comment: да да так и есть) тут все))) ок))) как мне сделать чтобы из другого меню хэндлер так же все вспоминал, только добавлял другие кнопки, соответствующие другому меню))), в данный момент, он прописан с одним меню и соответствующими к нему кнопками, вот как добавить другую менюху с другими кнопками)))? Благодарю!