# Как ограничить работу бота на определенной территории?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Мой бот получает геоданные пользователя, и должен ограничивать работу бота в области определенного региона. После получения локации пользователя он либо предоставляет доступ к своим дальнейшим функциям, либо наоборот.
Как осуществить изложенное в последнем предложении?

Comment: Нужно найти либу, которая сможет по координатам выдавать страну и завести белый/черный список стран

Comment: Или еще как вариант просто проверять IP на принадлежность к стране(региону).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1209080/234134 разбирайте ответ и если область допустима продолжайте код